# Insert a form into a page using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, append

I'm using jquery to insert a hidden form into a page (once the page has already loaded). For some reason the code is not working. Here is a sample of the code:

```
$(function(){
    $('body')
        .append('<form id="mySearch"></form>'); //append a new form element with id mySearch to <body>
    $('#mySearch') 
        .attr("action","mySearchPage.cfm") .attr("method","post") //set the form attributes
        //add in all the needed input elements
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" value="Search">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="txtField1" id="txtField1" value="">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="txtField2" id="txtField2" value="">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="selType" id="selType" value="0">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="selType2" id="selType2" value="2">')
});
```

The form is not being inserted into the body of the page. What am I doing wrong?

Update: I've found that when I use the code in a page on it's own it works correctly. When I try to integrate it into a large, already existing page it no longer works. Any ideas about what might cause the exact same code to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, it was just a syntax problem with an extra  tag in the file that included the javascript :P The code works now!

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body')
        .append('<form id="mySearch"></form>'); //append a new form element with id mySearch to <body>
    $('#mySearch') 
        .attr("action","mySearchPage.cfm") .attr("method","post") //set the form attributes
        //add in all the needed input elements
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="btnSearch" id="btnSearch" value="Search">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="txtField1" id="txtField1" value="">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="txtField2" id="txtField2" value="">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="selType" id="selType" value="0">')
        .append('<input type="hidden" name="selType2" id="selType2" value="2">')
});
```

Anyway you should absolutely avoid this kind of approach to add dynamic content to the dom.
The best technique is to create a single string containing all the necessary markup and inject it in one shot! Something like:

```
var HTML = '<form attributes><input><input>...</form>';
$("#container").html(HTML);
```

Comment: Also, can you explain why injecting a single string is the best technique?

Comment: $(function(){ != $(document).ready(function(){ ... and a single injection is better because you don't have to traverse the dom more than once nor invoke several methods.

Comment: The jquery API states that they are indeed identical: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: yes, theoretically they are identical, but I don't trust 100% the jQuery docs (I faced some issues time ago, that didn't match with the docs :P)... so I suggested you to try another syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, perhaps you don't want hidden form fields?

http://jsfiddle.net/M5vWR/

See this one with visible form elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/M5vWR/2/

Comment: I want them to be invisible. But they're not there at all. I've tried inspecting the page source, and it's not there.

Comment: inspect the current dom. "View Source" will only show you the raw markup.

Comment: it doesn't show up when I inspect the dom either. does it make a difference that this code is in a separate javascript file?

Comment: it shouldn't matter as long as its set up properly.

Comment: I looked at the fiddle but I'm not so familiar with fiddle... I see that it seems to work for you, but I still don't know why it doesn't work for me :-/